# How many Opportunity Attacks can a PC make during a round?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack

How many Opportunity Attacks (OA) does a PC get per round?

Example: if multiple foes go by a PC engaged in combat, and leaves their weapon reach, does the PC get an OA against each creature that goes by it?

Moving Around Other Creatures

> If you leave a hostile creature’s reach during your move, you provoke
>   an opportunity attack ...(Basic Rules p. 71:)

Opportunity Attack

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
>   can see moves out of your reach. (Basic Rules p. 73)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**You only get ONE reaction between the start of your turn and the start of your next turn**.

An Opportunity Attack is considered a Reaction (PHB pp195)

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature.

The Rules on Reactions are as follows (PHB pp190)

> When you take a reaction, you can't take another one until the start of your next turn.

To clarify for you and your players: not only do you only get one attempt at an Opportunity Attack with your reaction, but it also means that you have spent your reaction. That means other movement that might trigger an Opportunity Attack for you *would not* because you no longer have your reaction; and other spells/abilities/etc that utilize a reaction (like Shield, Featherfall, Counterspell) would also no longer be an option as you have used your reaction.

**What is a round?**

Although initiative is ordered from highest to lowest, that isn't what the technical round is for your character. A round is from the start of your turn to the start of your next turn.

[From Jeremy Crawford on Twitter (unofficially)](https://mobile.twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/845742198612094977)

> To the reaction rule, a round is measured from the start of your turn. You could take a reaction, then again after your turn starts.

Answer (score 9):

### One per reaction, unless a feature says otherwise

For instance, the fighting style Tunnel Fighter (from [UA: Light, Dark, Underdark!](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf)) says:

> you can make opportunity attacks without using your reaction

Since you don't use your reaction in this case, you can make several OAs per turn with Tunnel Fighter. Otherwise, you make only one or zero OAs per turn, as NautArch said, providing you still have your reaction **and you can use it** (there are several abilities, preventing creatures from taking reactions, like the Shocking Grasp spell).

There are also "OA-like" attacks, like the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sentinel) feat's third benefit (PHB, p. 169-170):

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn't have this feat), you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature

But it also expends your reaction (hence, can be done only once), despite not being an opportunity attack, and it does not trigger any "when you hit a creature with an opportunity attack" features.