# How can one make multiple opportunity attacks during one round?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reactions

The title is pretty straight-forward. By default, [players can make only one opportunity attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99152/how-many-opportunity-attacks-can-a-pc-take-during-a-round) per round, since it uses their reaction of which they only have one.

Which features, spells etc. exist that allow a player to make multiple opportunity attacks during one round? These attacks don't necessarily have to be able to occur during the same turn (nor do they have to be able to occur on different turns).

Comment: While it's an interesting question, after pondering from yesterday to today, I'm voting for closing as too broad. The reason is that seeing the answers, I don't think there is a "right answer" for a question like this, especially the way it's worded (which features, spells, etc. exist...). In particular, while it has applications in solving some problems, the question itself doesn't state an actual problem. I'm not sure the goal of the site is to make a reference manual where you can find "What spells do this particular thing?" answers. - well that is a large comment, sorry.

Comment: @HellSaint well, it's a Q&A site, not just a rules lawyering site. Regardless, the number of possible answers to this questioned (i.e. ways to make multiple OAs) is definitely finite (and very much so), so I don't think it's too broad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you noted in your answer, the [Cavalier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Cavalier), a fighter subclass from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 30-31), has this feature:

> ### Vigilant Defender
>
> Starting at 18th level, you respond to danger with extraordinary vigilance. In combat, you get a special reaction that you can take once on every creature’s turn, except your turn. You can use this special reaction only to make an opportunity attack, and you can’t use it on the same turn that you take your normal reaction.

This lets you make one extra opportunity attack on every creature's turn (except a turn in which you use your regular reaction).

Alternately, [Unearthed Arcana: Light, Dark, Underdark!](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf) features an additional Fighting Style option (for fighters, paladins, and rangers who have the Fighting Style class feature), the Tunnel Fighter fighting style:

> #### Tunnel Fighter
>
> You excel at defending narrow passages, doorways, and other tight spaces. As a bonus action, you can enter a defensive stance that lasts until the start of your next turn. While in your defensive stance, you can make opportunity attacks without using your reaction, and you can use your reaction to make a melee attack against a creature that moves more than 5 feet while within your reach.

This fighting style allows the character to make as many opportunity attacks as they can without using their reaction, and additionally allows them to use their reaction to attack a creature that moves around them within their reach - all for the cost of just a bonus action.

However, keep in mind that UA is playtest content, and may not be balanced. The two Fighting Style options from this 2015 UA (Close Quarters Shooter, and Tunnel Fighter) have not been published in any 5th edition book so far. It is possible that Wizards of the Coast deemed them unbalanced in their current form, or that Wizards decided the fighting styles required further tweaking/iterations before publication.

Especially by comparison to the Cavalier's 18th-level feature, the Tunnel Fighter fighting style seems quite overpowered, especially for a 1st-level fighter feature (or a 2nd-level feature for rangers and paladins).

Answer (score 8):

One feature I'm aware of is the level 18 feature of the *Fighter* subclass *Cavalier*:

> Vigilant Defender
>
> Starting at 18th level, you respond to danger with extraordinary vigilance. In combat, you get a special reaction that you can take once on every creature’s turn, except your turn. You can use this special reaction only to make an opportunity attack, and you can’t use it on the same turn that you take your normal reaction.

---

Another possibility is to *True Polymorph* into a creature such as the *Hydra* or *Marilith*, both of which can take multiple reactions each round. While the *Hydra* can only use these for opportunity attacks, *Mariliths* can take one reaction/turn, but they're normal reactions, usable for spells as well (at least RAW). *Hydras* can take more than one reaction on a single creatures turn, though.

Answer (score 4):

There's a way to get 2 opportunity attacks every time a creature would otherwise provoke only one, and against the same creature. You need the following to do so: War Caster and Green-Flame Blade or, optimally, Booming Blade.

The War Caster feat (PHB 170) very specifically states that when a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can *use your reaction* to **cast a spell** at the creature *rather than* making an opportunity attack.

"Rather than" is extremely important here.

The second piece of the puzzle lies in the "Mark" optional rule (DMG 271). Simply put, you can mark a creature when you make a **melee attack** against it and it grants you a free Opportunity Attack once per turn. Meaning you don't expend your reaction.

So, how do they come together?

1. What you want to do is have a creature provoke an opportunity attack from you.
2. *Rather than* make an opportunity attack though, you're going to cast a spell at it, which would be Booming Blade, which expends your reaction.
3. You must make sure to declare that you wish to use the melee attack component of Booming Blade to Mark the creature.
4. You use your Mark Opportunity Attack against the same creature, as it is still an opportunity attack and simply does not use your reaction. War Caster specifies that you can use your reaction to cast a spell (which you spent), so you don't get a second Booming Blade on them.

This allows you to deal the initial Booming Blade damage, the movement damage, as OAs are specified to occur just before the creature exits your reach. Meaning it is, in fact, voluntarily moving before the start of your next turn while Booming Blade would have already taken effect. And then, another melee attack that you gained by Marking and used for free.

Note: This can be extremely powerful if combined with the Polearm Master feat, Spell Sniper feat (or Sorcerer's Distant Spell Metamagic) and the Sentinel Feat. As it allows you to deal very heavy damage on another creature's turn **and** typically keep them at bay, depending on their reach. It's a costly build, but it's extremely powerful when it gets off. Top it off with Great Weapon Master feat and Fighter/Paladin's Great Weapon Fighting feature

Also Note: The Booming Blade can be Twinned, if you picked the Spell Sniper feat, to have another creature's movement allow you to hit an enemy who is already sitting in your reach.

Comment: Spell Sniper is only a factor if you're trying to use a polearm... That said, the rest of this appears technically correct, the best kind of the correct, but is likely to be considered very dodgy by many DMs.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site. The answer looks mostly fine so I removed the initial remark. Thank you for contributing and happy gaming!

Comment: interesting answer, but do note that twinning *Booming Blade* would invalidate it for *War Caster* - which states that "the spell must have a casting
time of 1 action and must target only that creature".

Comment: By my interpretation, *Booming Blade* would not be invalidated for *War Caster* by *Twinned Spell*. This is because the spell does, in fact, have a casting time of 1 action and targets only that creature. However, *Metamagic* is applied **during** the casting of a spell, meaning you would be applying this metamagic to warp the effects of the spell *after* it would have already fulfilled all the requirements for *War Caster*. It would seem odd to me that a metamagic that alters a spell **after** its requirements would have already been met, would now suddenly fail in the middle of its casting.

Comment: I don't think the Mark rules lets you make AoO against marked targets when you don't have a reaction.

"but the attacker can't make the attack if anything, such as the incapacitated condition or the shocking grasp spell, is preventing it from taking reactions."

The absence of a reaction is something preventing the attacker from taking reactions. It can't take reactions if it doesn't have them.

Further it states:

"The opportunity attack doesn't [B]expend[/B] the attacker's reaction"

Implying it must have a reaction that could otherwise be expended.

Answer (score 3):

### High level powers, or an optional DMG rule

As mentioned in other answers, there are some features of specific classes (Vigilant Defender for Cavalier) or creature types (Hydras or Marilith) that can allow creatures to take multiple reactions per round. But since true polymorph is a 9th level spell, these tactics will not be available until very high levels (17 or 18, depending on which tactic is being used).

There is also the optional rule in the DMG called Mark (DMG, p. 271)

> MARK This option makes it easier for melee combatants to harry each other with opportunity attacks.
>
> When a creature makes a melee attack, it can also mark its target.
>   Until the end of the attacker's next turn, any opportunity attack it
>   makes against the marked target has advantage. The opportunity attack
>   doesn't expend the attacker's reaction, but the attacker can't make
>   the attack if anything, such as the incapacitated condition or the
>   shocking grasp spell, is preventing it from taking reactions. The
>   attacker is limited to one opportunity attack per turn.

This is a **resource free option, which could be done by any creature regardless of level or class**. Of course, in order to use it to make more than two opportunity attacks in one round, a character would need to target multiple opponents in combat with melee attacks (two could be made from a Marked target and a second target which uses up your Reaction). Since it is usually advantageous to focus attacks on an single enemy until they fall, this strategy does have a tactical cost. But it is a viable way to gain multiple opportunity attacks in a single round.